# Castle WCF Facility, Use of generic interface for non generic contract

Tags: wcf, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, wcffacility

I tried to minimize writing of code for WCF CRUD part of big project with use of generics and castle WCF facility.

I have WCF service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IResourceService : ICRUDService<DTOResource>
{
    [OperationContract]
    DTOResource Get(long id);
}
```

and `generic` interface

```
public interface ICRUDService<T> where T is IDTO
{
    T Get(long id);
}
```

also generic `MVC` controller (*1 controller for all basic crud for dtos and services*)

```
public class CRUDController<T> : Controller where T is IDTO
{
    readonly ICRUDService<T> service;
    public CRUDController(ICRUDService<T> service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }   
}
```

On the client side i register WCF client in `Windsor` Container

```
Component
  .For<IResourceService , ICRUDService<DTOResource>>()
  .AsWcfClient(... standard stuff... )
```

Everythig is working fine, components and services registered, controller created properly,
service

```
readonly ICRUDService<T> service;
```

in controller is of type

```
Castle.Proxies.IResourceService
```

But when i try to use service in controller i have error

```
Method Get is not supported on this proxy, this can happen if the method is
 not marked with OperationContractAttribute or if the interface type is not 
 marked with ServiceContractAttribute.
```

When in controller i hardcode cast

```
((IResourceService)service).Get(id);
```

all is running properly, so i believe this problem is solvable.

I've also tried to use Forward (*with same result*) :

```
Component
  .For<IActionTypeService>
  .Forward<ICRUDService<DTOResource>>().AsWcfClient(...
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end i had to use 'Channel Factory' on client side.
I was able to use Windsor `WCF Facility` on server side to register generic contract :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICRUDService<I>
{
    [OperationContract]
    I Get(int id);
}
```

with generic implementation

```
public class CRUDService<I, IEntity> : ServiceBase, ICRUDService<I>
{
    public I Get(int id)
    {            
        ...
    }
```

in standard way (for multiple types)

```
private void InstallExample<I, IEntity>(IWindsorContainer container)
{
container.Register(
    Component
        .For<ICRUDService<I>>()
        .ImplementedBy(CRUDService<I, IEntity>)
        .Named("somename")
        .AsWcfService(
            new DefaultServiceModel()
                .Hosted()
                .PublishMetadata(x => x.EnableHttpGet())
                .AddEndpoints(WcfEndpoint
                .BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding())
                .At("someAddress")
            )
        )
        .LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation();
}
```

with fileless activation in `web.config`

```
<add factory="Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration" service="ClientService" relativeAddress="./ClientService.svc" />
```

On server side it works perfectly. Sadly on client side i didn't found working solution for WCFFacility and i had to use `ChannelFactory` (which is working perfectly)

```
ChannelFactory<ICRUDService<I>> factory = new ChannelFactory<ICRUDService<I>>(someBinding, someEndpoint);
```

For the rest (standard non generic services i'm using `WCF Facility` without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put the ServiceContract attribute on ICrudService<>, add the OperationContract to the method there and remove the duplicate declaration of Get() from IResourceService.